# How do you use colspan and rowspan?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have data

```
this.input = [
  { id: "1", text: "text 1", value: "value 1", desc: "desc1" },
  { id: "2", text: "text 1", value: "value 2", desc: "desc2" },
  { id: "3", text: "text 2", value: "value 3", desc: "desc3" }
]
```

So, I want merge rows and columns.

result:

[image]

Can you please help me? Thank you!

Comment: please show what have you tried?

Comment: I try but not correct.
<table class="table table-sm">
        <tr *ngFor="let data of input">
          <td rowspan="2">{{data.text}}</td>
          <td>{{data.value}}</td>
          <td>{{data.desc}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>

Comment: Has your problem been solved? you need to group your object at first. check my naswer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to group your data with `text` key like this:

```
  this.Groupedinput = this.input.map(x => x.text)
    .filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v)==i)
    .map(x => ({ 
      text: x, 
      array: this.input.filter(y => y.text === x)
    }));
```

And then you should create nested `*ngFor` like this:

```
<table class="table table-sm">
  <tr *ngFor="let data of Groupedinput; let i=index">
      <td>{{data.text}}</td>
      <td>
        <tr *ngFor="let innerdata of data.array">
            <td>{{innerdata.value}}</td>
            <td>{{innerdata.desc}}</td>
        </tr>      
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is working sample I created for you: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hello-world-gw8hbm?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

And the result:

[image]